# View kubectl logs page by page on bash terminal

Tags: bash, kubectl, xargs

Team, 
On bash I run below to view logs but when they are huge the terminal all is all occupied dumping them out and i can't stop it for minutes.

Is there a way i can execute kubectl on bash in a a way that it shows logs only till shell screen size and then i use return key or spacebar to see more ? just like journalctl? but i want to achieve this when using kubectl.

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test
```

Above displans 10K lines at a time which i don't want. Neither I want to exec on to the pod and see log file physically. any hints? or is there something like which displays last 100lines? or first with xargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
kubectl logs --tail=100 test-pod -n namespace-test
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to obtain that.

**1) less**

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test | less
```

This command will allow you to read logs page by page from top to the bottom. You can use arrows to go up or down.

**2) --tail=**

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test --tail=500
```

Will display last 500 rows of logs

**3) pipeline with grep**

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test | grep <some_phrase>
```

It will allow you to find logs with given phrases. Please note that you can join commands via pipeline i.e

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test --tail=500 | grep <some_phrase>
```

**4) --since=**

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test --since=60
```

It display logs from last 60 seconds

5) **--since-time=''**

Similar to previous one. It will display logs from provided time. Format in this command is

> 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:ssZ'

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test --since-time='2019-04-23T12:00:00Z'
```

You could hear about `more` option like but it is old format. You can scroll only from top to the bottom, you cannot go up.

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n namespace-test | more
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below command to get all pods logs in kubernets along with page by page.

```
kubectl get pods -n default|grep -v NAME|awk '{print $1}'|while read pods;do kubectl logs $pods;echo;done|more
```